# Neo4j Best way to export database to CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have tried the Cypher export csv, but the query itself takes too long, and it didn't seem practical since i needed to export a whole database which ranges upwards to a few gigabytes in size.

Is there a tool that lets me export a huge database in fairly good time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_to_csv) procedures. This is straightforward to install within your Neo4j environment and provide many additional functionalities, e.g. to export your results or data to .csv file.